# ASP doesn't recognize leading whitespace when calculating string length

Tags: javascript, asp-classic

This multiline string when created by a browser has the expected length:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
var s = "\
    a";
document.write(s.length);
</script>
```

Outputs 5

But when executed as ASP server side scritp it outputs 1:

```
<%@ Language=JavaScript %>
<%
var s = "\
    a";
Response.Write(s.length);
%>
```

What is happening is that the ASP version of Javascript is eating the leading white spaces when used in multiline strings.

How to make the ASP version behave the same as the browser version?

Comment: My Google-fu suggests you try `len(s)`;

Comment: len() is vbscript: you may be confusing ASP with a language...

Comment: what are you trying to acheive - are you just using multiline for code readability (since the string won't actually contain any linebreaks)?  Bottom line i think is that since that approach is "non-standard" you can't rely on different hosts behaving the same way.

Comment: @Tim Williams Yes readability. I'm using it to write dynamic SQL queries which are ugly in the source code when concatenating strings. To make the linebreak i finish the line with `\n\\`. This behavior is no problem when reading the query in the source code but when I want to show the real query in the browser with the replaced parameters it gets left aligned as the leading spaces are lost.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you include a `\` at the start of your line, asp recognizes the whitespace.

```
<%@ Language=JavaScript %>
<%
var s = "\
\    a";
Response.Write(s.length);
%>
```

I wasn't familiar with using the `\` character to create multiline strings.  Neat stuff, but I couldn't find documentation for that.  I guess it's just escaping the line break?  Do you have a link to a reference?

**Edit** Additionally, this code:

```
<pre>
<%
var s = "\
    unescaped";
Response.Write(s);
Response.Write("\n");
s = "\
\    escaped";
Response.Write(s);
%>
</pre>
```

Gives this output:

```
unescaped
    escaped
```

Comment: It looks like your solution is good enough. As pointed by Tim it is a non-standard usage. But a simple [googling](http://www.google.com/search?q=javascript+multiline+string&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8&aq=t&rls=org.mozilla:en-US:unofficial&client=firefox-a) shows it is accepted by all browsers.

Answer (score 0):

If you are trying to see multiple spaces in html, it is to note that multiple spaces will be collapsed when html is rendered. Use `'&nbsp'` when non-breaking space is desired in html output.

Comment: I'm rendering it wrapped in a `<pre>` tag which preserves white space. The problem is that the ASP version of javascript is "eating" the leading white spaces in multiline strings as shown when checking the string length.